# Sponsoring a community member to attend the 2011 GDC

Tags: discussion

The 2011 Game Developers Conference is Feb 28 - Mar 4 in San Francisco

http://www.gdconf.com/

**We would like to sponsor someone from the gamedev.stackexchange.com community to attend this conference!**

That means we will cover your airfare, hotel, and travel fees to make it to the summit, so long as you spend a little bit of time speaking / networking / blogging / sharing during the conference, and of course mention our fine, fine game development community here. :)

So, the question part of the question:

- Does this make sense? What else should we be thinking of for the conference?
- Who would like to go?
- Who is willing and able to speak / network / blog / share at the conference?

Robert Cartaino, our community coordinator, will be following up.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. A booth would be cool, I would LOOOOOVE to go but I have school D:. Can I call dibs on next year? :D

Answer (score 6):

Other things to think about, if you have the cash, is more general sponsorship stuff.

http://www.jointhegamenetwork.com/event/gdc/sponsoropp.html

Speaking doesn't really make sense.  Maybe if we knew somebody who was already going to GDC and giving a talk and could plug the site at the end or something.  But that might be against the rules, I'm not sure.  It's a bit of a long shot either way.

Blogging, would that be on, say, a personal blog site or would that be an article or two written for the stackexchange blog itself?

Personally I've never been (so I really don't know a good way of promoting a site like this at a place like that, other than the usual "wear a t-shirt with a large logo and hand out business cards") but I wouldn't mind going.

Answer (score 5):

I think sending someone to GDC to spread the word about our game development community, and share their experience with others who aren't able to attend, is a wonderful idea!

Off the top of my head, here are a few ways I think we could spread the word about GDSE (from least to most expensive):

- Spokesperson – Essentially the idea presented by NAME – Send someone to GDC to spread awareness via word of mouth (and business cards/brochures)
- Swag - People like free stuff. A well designed shirt could do wonders!
- Advertisement – Designing an interesting banner to be hung near areas of high traffic could increase web traffic
- Booth – The traditional way of promoting products/services at GDC
- Party - A GDSE (co)sponsored party would be a wonderful way to raise awareness, although I imagine this could option could be quite expensive, and would require a lot of planning

Whoever we send to GDC needs to be sociable, professional, and in tune with the industry, as they will be representing ALL of us. :)

Comment: excellent suggestions, all. This is something we want to get serious about, as we believe so deeply in learning, and going to a conference to speak or participate -- and bring that back to our community through deeper participation or blogging -- is a great way to learn.

Comment: Personally, I think the challenge we're up against is figuring out a way to (easily) attract a large number GDC attendees to GDSE. I imagine most people on this site could write a few blog entries recounting their GDC experience, but the true value we gain from sending someone to GDC is the potential to increase the (aspiring) professional presence on this website.